# Make cube dimension group by range

Tags: ssas, olap-cube, ssas-2008

I have the AdventureWorksDW2008R loaded and have been able to create a basic cube in Visual Studio. I am trying to find information on how I could create grouping for an attribute such as [Product].[Size].[Size]. What I would like to do is have to the option to select 0 - 40, 41 - 50, 51 - 60 etc.

Could someone point me the right direction to be able to build this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a case statement in your view that splits out the size categories for products.

You then add in that attribute to your dimension.

You could also look up the Discretization setting.

Comment: Thanks I will look into Discretization setting